# How to Display Value Created from API Onto My Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, nodemon

So I am working with this API and it auto calculates the delivery fee based on the address you input.

Here's the API docs I am using
https://developer.doordash.com/en-US/api/drive#operation/DeliveryQuote

So when I add my values to my form and get my data, it logs the fee in my console like this

[image]

My issue is how do I get this value from the data field?

I tried to do

```
 const response = await client.createDelivery(
      {
        order_value: req.body.item1,
        fee: fee,
        tip: req.body.item1,
      },
      console.log(fee)
    );

    console.log(response);

    res.send(response);
  }
 )
```

But it says fee is not defined?

I also tried `fee: ""` and that doesn't work either.

I even put `console.log(data.fee)` and it says data is not defined

My last attempt I change it to `console.log(response.fee)` and it still showed undefined in the console?

How do I even get the fee value to console.log?

Note I am using express and for my tip value I have my input form named "item1" so I can access it by saying `req.body.item1` to get that value

However, for the fee value its auto generated by the API, so I can't change it or update it manually myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
console.log(response.data.fee)
```

And I am not sure what your `client.createDelivery` does. If it sends response, then you need to display it like

```
const response = await client.createDelivery(
  {
    order_value: req.body.item1,
    fee: fee,
    tip: req.body.item1,
  },
  console.log(fee)
).then((res) => res.json()).then((resData) => console.log(resData.data.fee));
```

Answer (score 0):

##### this is what the return object looks like

```json
{
  data {
    currency: 'USD',
    fee: 975,
    otherData: otherData,
  }
}
```

##### what you must do to fix your problem is first dive into the `data` object then retrieve `fee` from that object like `data.fee`

```js
const response = await client.createDelivery(
  {
    order_value: req.body.item1,
    fee: data.fee, // changed from fee to data.fee
    tip: req.body.item1,
  },
  console.log(data.fee)
);
```

##### without retrieving it from the `data` object there would be no fee object to grab which is whats making it undefined...

Comment: since i am using express you need to do response.data.fee , so I figured it out